# What is the difference between private and protected members of C++ classes?

Tags: c++, class, oop, private, protected

What is the difference between `private` and `protected` members in C++ classes?

I understand from best practice conventions that variables and functions which are not called outside the class should be made `private`—but looking at my MFC project, MFC seems to favor `protected`.

What's the difference and which should I use?

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Private members are only accessible within the class defining them.

Protected members are accessible in the class that defines them and in classes that inherit from that class.

Both are also accessible by friends of their class, and in the case of protected members, by friends of their derived classes.

Use whatever makes sense in the context of your problem. You should try to make members private whenever you can to reduce coupling and protect the implementation of the base class, but if that's not possible, then use protected members.

Check [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/basics-of-inheritance) for a better understanding of the issue. [This question about protected variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011/protected-member-variables) might also help.

Comment: The link to C++ FAQ Lite has moved to https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/basics-of-inheritance

Comment: I have protected member function in class Item named setCountry then I derived one more class and name it Fashion then I defined one more class from Fashion and name it Cloth, but setCountry is not accessible in Cloth. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 161):

**Public** members of a class A are accessible for all and everyone.

**Protected** members of a class A are not accessible outside of A's code, but is accessible from the code of any class derived from A.

**Private** members of a class A are not accessible outside of A's code, or from the code of any class derived from A.

So, in the end, choosing between protected or private is answering the following questions: **How much trust are you willing to put into the programmer of the derived class?**

**By default**, assume the derived class is not to be trusted, and **make your members private**. If you have a very good reason to give free access of the mother class' internals to its derived classes, then you can make them protected.

Comment: The derived class should be a type of your class, and the protected data of the base class is part of the data of the derived class. The writer of the derived class is expected to handle this data properly or it is a bug.

Private data in a base class is, however, something the writer of the derived class does not control.

Comment: @CashCow `the protected data of the base class is part of the data of the derived class.` Indeed. Isn't it better, then, to have the writer of the derived class declare that data in their class, instead of mine?... :-) ... `The writer of the derived class is expected to handle this data properly or it is a bug.` In the NVI pattern, the aim is to make everything private, including methods, to limit the damage the derived class writer could do to the hierarchy. Protected methods are already a potential problem. I am not convinced aggravating this by using protected state is the right approach.

Comment: It could be, which would require you to have virtual "getters" in the base class to access it. And whilst you can have in-between classes to do the different ways the data pattern can be implemented, it is not always practical to do so.

For example, a "pattern", common in languages that don't have a "const" modifier albeit not necessary most of the time in C++ is to have a read-only base class and writable derived classes. In C++ this can also be nice simply because you want more than one possible way to load in (initialise) the data.

Comment: There are various ways to do that. Make your serialisation classes friends. Put all your data into a struct with public access but your class has a private member of this variable.... Protected  members and derived classes to load it from whatever source is sometimes easier.

Comment: I am not convinced that private by default is a good policy. It seems like I encounter the situation in which I cannot use a closed source library because it cannot be made to do what I need because I can't manipulate things that have no good reason to be private far more frequently than I encounter the situation in which I don't know better than to manipulate things which have a good reason to be private. I think being humble and over trusting is a better approach than being arrogant and over defensive. Resist tight policies. Tight policies advance the cause of centralized totalitarianism.

Comment: @Shavais : "I think being humble and over trusting is a better approach than being arrogant and over defensive" ... You are in the minority. I, for one, disagree with that approach... "Tight policies advance the cause of centralized totalitarianism" ... This is out of topic, in addition to be false, and misleading. For example, tight policies is what enables spaceships to reach the moon, or even planes to fly securely. The "737 Max", the "Ohio train derailment " and the "United Kingdom BSE outbreak" catastrophes are prime examples of being "over trusting" instead of tightly regulating.

Comment: @paercebal: fair points

Answer (score 81):

Protected members can be accessed from derived classes. Private ones can't.

```
class Base {

private: 
  int MyPrivateInt;
protected: 
  int MyProtectedInt;
public:
  int MyPublicInt;
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:
  int foo1()  { return MyPrivateInt;} // Won't compile!
  int foo2()  { return MyProtectedInt;} // OK  
  int foo3()  { return MyPublicInt;} // OK
};‌‌

class Unrelated 
{
private:
  Base B;
public:
  int foo1()  { return B.MyPrivateInt;} // Won't compile!
  int foo2()  { return B.MyProtectedInt;} // Won't compile
  int foo3()  { return B.MyPublicInt;} // OK
};
```

In terms of "best practice", it depends. If there's even a faint possibility that someone might want to derive a new class from your existing one and need access to internal members, make them Protected, not Private. If they're private, your class may become difficult to inherit from easily.

Comment: I beg to differ: if there's a faint possibility that _no_ subclass is going to need it, make it private.  Unless you _intend_ to have your class subclassed, use the template method pattern.

Comment: If you don't intend to have your class subclassed, make it final. Private vs protected is only an issue if the class is going to be subclassed.

Answer (score 26):

The reason that MFC favors protected, is because it is a framework. You probably want to subclass the MFC classes and in that case a protected interface is needed to access methods that are not visible to general use of the class.

Answer (score 10):

It all depends on what you want to do, and what you want the derived classes to be able to see.

```
class A
{
private:
    int _privInt = 0;
    int privFunc(){return 0;}
    virtual int privVirtFunc(){return 0;}
protected:
    int _protInt = 0;
    int protFunc(){return 0;}
public:
    int _publInt = 0;
    int publFunc()
    {
         return privVirtFunc();
    }
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    virtual int privVirtFunc(){return 1;}
public:
    void func()
    {
        _privInt = 1; // wont work
        _protInt = 1; // will work
        _publInt = 1; // will work
        privFunc(); // wont work
        privVirtFunc(); // will work, simply calls the derived version.
        protFunc(); // will work
        publFunc(); // will return 1 since it's overridden in this class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Attributes and methods marked as `protected` are -- unlike private ones -- still visible in subclasses.

Unless you don't want to use or provide the possibility to override the method in possible subclasses, I'd make them `private`.

Comment: A derived class can override its base's private virtual functions

Answer (score 6):

Sure take a look at the [Protected Member Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011/protected-member-variables) question.  It is recommended to use private as a default (just like C++ `class`ses do) to reduce coupling.  Protected member variables are most always a bad idea, protected member functions can be used for e.g. the Template Method pattern.

Comment: Funny, I edited that to my post before I saw yours. Upvoted because birds of a feather stumble upon the same link :)

Answer (score 4):

Protected members can only be accessed by descendants of the class, and by code in the same module. Private members can only be accessed by the class they're declared in, and by code in the same module.

Of course friend functions throw this out the window, but oh well.

Answer (score 4):

private members are only accessible from within the class, protected members are accessible in the class and derived classes. It's a feature of inheritance in OO languages.

You can have private, protected and public inheritance in C++, which will determine what derived classes can access in the inheritance hierarchy. C# for example only has public inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

**private** = accessible by the mothership (base class) only
(ie only my parent can go into my parent's bedroom)

**protected** = accessible by mothership (base class), and her daughters
(ie only my parent can go into my parent's bedroom, but gave son/daughter permission to walk into parent's bedroom)

**public** = accessible by mothership (base class), daughter, and everyone else
(ie only my parent can go into my parent's bedroom, but it's a house party - mi casa su casa)

Answer (score 2):

Since no public member function is needed to fetch and update protected members in the derived class, this increases the efficiency of code and reduces the amount of code we need to write. However, programmer of the derived class is supposed to be aware of what he is doing.

Comment: You can always use an inline function implemented in the class declaration.  The compiler will optimise that away (and that would be a good way to enforce read-only access to a private member variable, for example).

Comment: @PaulSanders inline != optimized away. Compiler can inline functions not marked as inline, vice versa.

Comment: @MattF.I didn't mean use the `inline` keyword.  I meant put the implementation in the header file so that the compiler can see it and therefore inline it / optimise it (although, these days, you can enable link time optimisation to do the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

`private` is preferred for member data. Members in C++ classes are `private` by default.

`public` is preferred for member functions, though it is a matter of opinion. At least some methods must be accessible. `public` is accessible to all. It is the most flexible option and least safe. Anybody can use them, and anybody can misuse them.

`private` is not accessible at all. Nobody can use them outside the class, and nobody can misuse them. Not even in derived classes.

`protected` is a compromise because it can be used in derived classes. When you derive from a class, you have a good understanding of the base class, and you are careful not to misuse these members.

MFC is a C++ wrapper for Windows API, it prefers `public` and `protected`. Classes generated by Visual Studio wizard have an ugly mix of `protected`, `public`, and `private` members. But there is some logic to MFC classes themselves.

Members such as `SetWindowText` are `public` because you often need to access these members.

Members such as `OnLButtonDown`, handle notifications received by the window. They should not be accessed, therefore they are `protected`. You can still access them in the derived class to override these functions.

Some members have to do threads and message loops, they should not be accessed or override, so they are declared as `private`

In C++ structures, members are `public` by default. Structures are usually used for data only, not methods, therefore `public` declaration is considered safe.

Comment: You write "Members in C++ classes are protected by default". According to the standard, they are either private or public by default, depending on which keyword was used in the definition (14p3). Does Microsoft deviate from the standard here?

Comment: @AlexanderKlauer I was wrong, it's `private` by default in Visual Studio. It's `private` by default in gcc as well, it's never `public` by default. Unless I am wrong again. I can't find the standard you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I was referring to the C++ 17 standard. The C++ 11 standard has the same wording in 11p3. Could you update your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Private :** Accessible by class member functions & friend function or friend class.
For C++ class this is default access specifier.

**Protected:** Accessible by class member functions, friend function or friend class & derived classes.

- You can keep class member variable or function (even typedefs or inner classes) as private or protected as per your requirement.
- Most of the time you keep class member as a private and add get/set functions to encapsulate. This helps in maintenance of code.
- Generally private function is used when you want to keep your public functions modular or to eliminate repeated code instead of writing whole code in to single function. This helps in maintenance of code.

[Refer this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

- **Private**: It is an access specifier. By default the instance (member) variables or the methods of a class in c++/java are private. During inheritance, the code and the data are always inherited but is not accessible outside the class. We can declare our data members as private so that no one can make direct changes to our member variables and we can provide public getters and setters in order to change our private members. And this concept is always applied in the business rule.
- **Protected**: It is also an access specifier. In C++, the protected members are accessible within the class and to the inherited class but not outside the class. In Java, the protected members are accessible within the class, to the inherited class as well as to all the classes within the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Private member can be accessed only in same class where it has declared where as protected member can be accessed in class where it is declared along with the classes which are inherited by it .

Answer (score 0):

A protected nonstatic base class member can be accessed by members and friends of any classes derived from that base class by using one of the following:

- A pointer to a directly or indirectly derived class
- A reference to a directly or indirectly derived class
- An object of a directly or indirectly derived class

Answer (score 0):

> The `protected` keyword specifies access to class members in the
> member-list up to the next access specifier (`public` or `private`) or the
> end of the class definition. `Class members` declared as `protected` can
> be used only by the following:
>
> - Member functions of the class that originally declared these members.
> - Friends of the class that originally declared these members.
> - Classes derived with public or protected access from the class that originally declared these members.
> - Direct privately derived classes that also have private access to protected members.
>
> When preceding the name of a base class, the `protected` keyword
> specifies that the public and protected members of the base class are
> protected members of its derived classes.
>
> Protected members are not as private as `private` members, which are
> accessible only to members of the class in which they are declared,
> but they are not as public as public members, which are accessible in
> any function.
>
> Protected members that are also declared as `static` are accessible to
> any `friend` or member function of a derived class. Protected members
> that are not declared as static are accessible to friends and member
> functions in a derived class only through a pointer to, reference to,
> or object of the derived class.

[protected (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/protected-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between private and protected members in C++ classes?

Other answers have stated:

- public - accessible by all.
- protected - accessible by derived classes (and friends).
- private - restricted.

> What's the difference and which should I use?

The [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-protected) gives the advice that data should always be private.  I think this is good advice as it makes for 'data spaghetti' when you have derived classes that can access protected data.  It makes much more sense for functions to be protected, but it depends on the use case.

For functions you have a choice.  For data, you should make it private and provide protected accessor functions if needed.  This gives more control over the class data.

Answer (score -3):

private and protected access modifiers are one and same only that protected members of the base class can be accessed outside the scope of the base class in the child(derived)class.
It also applies the same to inheritance .
But with the private modifier the members of the base class can only be accessed in the scope or code of the base class and its friend functions only''''

Comment: What value does your answer add over the other answers?