# Private methods and properties vs public ones regarding their memory footprints in C# (and other languages)

Tags: c#, memory, properties

I remember a discussion I recently had with a fellow developer about the memory footprint of private vs public properties. I stated that private ones have less of a footprint than public ones. He claimed it makes no difference. By the way, we were talking about C#.

**Who is right and why?**

Apparently there are differences in languages. I'm curious what they are as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the context of what language?

**In most languages**, changing a method's accessibility from `public` to `private` or vice-versa **will not at all affect its memory footprint**.  This is because the actual implementation and the actual invocation of the method does not change, only the way access to it is enforced (either at compile-time, or at run-time, based on the programming language in question.)

**What *will* have an effect on memory footprint are other qualifiers**, such as **`final` in Java, `virtual` in C++, `static`, etc.**  These qualifiers may either directly influence memory footprint (the presence or absence of a corresponding entry in the class [`vtable`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table)), or indirectly influence memory footprint because of certain optimization assumptions that can be made by the compiler or by the runtime (e.g. non-`virtual`, `static` and/or `final` methods can be inlined, thus arguably increasing performance -- and *most definitely* increasing memory footprint.)

---

**Of greater importance than memory footprint**, when discussing how a method should be qualified, is what you can do to both (1) have the compiler (or the runtime, as depending on the language) validate some of your assumptions and intentions, and (2) convey those assumptions and intentions to the programmer who will review, reverse-engineer, alter, re-factor etc. the code after you:

- `private`: do other classes, or descendants of this class, need direct access to this method?  If not, make it `private`.
- `protected`: do descendants of this class (or this class itself), but no other classes (except maybe `friend` classes), need direct access to this method?  If so, make it `protected`.
- `static`: does the method require access to member variables or to `this`?  If not, it should be `static` (e.g. a utility method that depends solely on its arguments)
- `const`: does the method alter member variables or call non-`const` member methods on `this` or member variables?  If not, it should be `const` (e.g. a getter)
- `virtual`: will the method need to be overridden?  If not, it should *not* be `virtual`
- `abstract` (or pure virtual): does the method need to have an implementation in this class, if this class' descendants will override it?  If not, make it `abstract` (or `pure virtual`)
- etc.

There are miscellaneous articles, lectures and posts out there regarding best practices for the above, transcending the boundaries of many a programming language:

- [access permissions and encapsulation](https://agora.cs.illinois.edu/download/attachments/19923932/lecture19.pdf?version=1)
- [encapsulation](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/class.html#fqa-7.4)
- [private vs. protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c)
- etc.

Comment: The discussion was about C#. But it seems there are differences between languages?

Comment: @Kriem: Not necessarily, but it's hard to speak about "all" languages and still be accurate. I suggest you update your question to make the context clear.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no difference. The property itself is just code and the metadata for it. Both are needed whether the property is private or public. Why would it make a difference?

Comment: do you have numbers to back that up? I would be curious due to how external assemblies can reference public methods, but have no access to private ones.

Comment: (Assuming .NET) The metadata states the access level, and the CLR (and compiler) check it when you compile against them. What bit of information *wouldn't* be needed for private properties? Note that the name etc is still in the metadata, as you can tell with reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see private versus public making a difference is if you're obfuscating your code. By default, an obfuscator typically won't obfuscate the names of public members because then you won't be able to reflect on them. That will cost you a very small amount of memory, since the names of members are included in an assembly's metadata.

Note that I'm talking tiny amounts of savings here. Hardly worth mentioning really. But it's Friday afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Making a property or method private can enhance execution speed because the compiler may be more likely to inline the code, but I don't know of any instances where this reduces the memory footprint (Inlining may actually increase footprint at the benefit of speed).

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. And, even if there were, it would have to be pretty brutal to be worth changing your accessors to accommodate it.