# What is the goal from using "protected"?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Private and Protected Members : C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c)

Why use the keyword "protected"? What does it mean?

Comment: You should really read this if you haven't done it already: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html

Comment: Also, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c

Comment: Perhaps you should read a book on C++ before you ask such a question.

Answer (score 4):

Technically it means:

Members marked as protected are visible to the owning class and classes derive from the owning class.

In Context:

```
      P
      r 
      o  
 P    t    p
 u    e    r
 b    c    v
 l    t    a
 i    e    t
 c    d    e
 ===========
 Y    N    N   Accesses by global function
 Y    N    N   Accessed by a member of another class
 Y    Y    N   Accessed by a member of derived class
 Y    Y    Y   Accessed by a member of the same class
```

Answer (score 2):

`protected` is similar to `private` in that classes and code external to our class cannot access these members of our class.

The difference is that `protected` members can be accessed by classes that derive from ours, while `private` members can't.

Answer (score 0):

Protected is an access level modifier that can be applied to members of classes in Java.  The list of access level modifiers in order of least to most restrictive are *public*, *protected*, *package* (no modifier), or *private*.

The *protected* modifier allows any child classes to access the member.

Comment: This question was tagged c++ though

Comment: Important details like that belong in the question, not just the tags.