# Issue having access to private member in a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

So in the header file of my derived class OrderedList I am inheriting some of the functionality of my previously created List class by telling the compiler to use a base class method by `using List<DataType>::examplefunction;`. All the functions which are not being overrided and that are being declared in the aforementioned way are private members of OrderedList.

So when I run my program, I obtain the error in Microsoft Visual Studio of:

> error C2248: 'OrderedList::examplefunction' : cannot access private member declared in class 'OrderedList'

examplefunction is public in the base class List.

Here is a concrete example of what I am working with:

In OrderedList.h,

```
private: 
using List<DataType>::remove;
```

In List.h,

```
public:
void remove () throw ( logic_error );
```

And where remove is in List.cpp as,

```
void List<DataType>::remove () throw ( logic_error ) 
{ // Do some operations// 
}
```

Also the declaration in my OrderedList header file is like this:

```
#include "List.cpp"

template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
class OrderedList : public List<DataType>
```

If anyone could enlighten me to what is causing the issue that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Give bigger part of your code, not just the using stmt.

Comment: I added more code. Hopefully this will help you. Is there anything specific that you are looking for?

Comment: Your parts of code are still not enough to understand your problem.

Comment: What else do you want me to post? There's really not much more involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the inherited methods to public and the data members to protected in the OrderedList header file worked.

**Update**

So this was about a year ago. However, it seems so blatantly obvious now. The instructions that were given said to declare the inherited methods from the `base class` (`List`) as `private`, but in `main` which was provided by the author of the textbook (for testing purposes) some of the inherited methods were being called. Which while being `private` were not able to be called by the instance of `OrderedList` that was being created in `main`.

The instructions were later corrected by our instructor, but sometimes as a student you can follow along to closely.

Answer (score 1):

If exampleFunction is private in your List class, your OrderedList class will not be able to access it. Make it protected instead. See [Private and Protected Members : C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c)

Comment: exampleFunction is public in List class.

Comment: Are you accessing any private methods/members from exampleFunction?

Comment: No, but it is accessing protected data members.