# Virtual functions error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So I made this class:

```
    class Book
    {
        public:
            Book(string newTitle = "???", string newAuthor = "???");
            virtual ~Book();

            string getTitle();
            string getAuthor();
            void setTitle(string  newTitle);
            void setAuthor(string newAuthor);

            virtual string allInfo();

        private:
            string title;
            string author;
    };
```

And I was going to cover the `allInfo()`-function in two other classes
One called `HardcoverBooks` and another called `AudioBooks`. Both inheriting from `Book`.

This is what I did subsequently in the `.cpp` files in both classes, first the `AudioBook` class:

```
string AudioBook::allInfo(){
    stringstream newString;

    newString<<"Title: "<<this->title<<endl<<"Author: "<<this->author<<endl
             <<"Narrator: "<<this->narrator<<endl
             <<"Length(in minutes):     "<<this->length<<endl<<endl;

    return newString.str();
}
```

And this in the `HardcoverBook` class:

```
string HardcoverBook::allInfo(){
    stringstream newString;

    newString<<"Title: "<<this->title<<endl<<"Author: "<<this->author<<endl
             <<"Pages: "<<this->pages<<endl<<endl;

    return newString.str();
}
```

Everything is working fine and dandy,except that the `AudioBook` class is complaining about this:

> include\Book.h||In member function 'virtual std::string
>   AudioBook::allInfo()':| include\Book.h|41|error: 'std::string
>   Book::title' is private| mningsuppgiftIIB\src\AudioBook.cpp|27|error:
>   within this context| include\Book.h|42|error: 'std::string
>   Book::author' is private| mningsuppgiftIIB\src\AudioBook.cpp|27|error:
>   within this context| ||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|

But in `HardcoverBook` it doesn't complain about this at all,strangely enough.

My questions:

1. What do I do to make this work? (i.e. to make both classes be able to use the function `allInfo()` in their own way)
2. Why doesn't it work like this?

EDIT:
This is some homework I'm doing,and one of the requirements is to make the member variables and properties private. So protected does work,kudos for that guys,but I'll add another bonus question:

1. How do I make it work with private member variables?

Comment: make `string title;` and `string author;` protected fields

Comment: Others already answered with making them protected. You can also consider providing public accessors if you want to prevent subclasses from modifying those members.

Edit: Or just use the accessors you already declared...

Comment: I'm doing this as homework,and one of the requirements is to make the member variables and properties private. Should've probably mentioned that before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `title` and `author` members are `private`. Which means that they are not visible in sub-classes, like `AudioBook`.

In order to make them visible to sub-classes you need to make these members `protected` rather than `private`.

Another option is to leave the member fields as private, and add protected or public access methods to allow the values to be read. For example:

```
public:
    string getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }
```

I would also comment that I don't understand why you are using `this->` to access members of your class. There's no need for that and it's usually best to simply omit it.

---

Without seeing your homework assignment, I'm not 100% sure what to make of the requirement that

> member variables and properties are private

My guess is that your task is to override `allInfo()`. You are being asked to extend the `string` returned to include all the information included by the base class implementation, and add some more.

Your current attempt simply duplicates the code in `Book::allInfo()`. And that's the problem. In order for that to work, the derived classes need access to the private members. And you are not allowed to do that. So, your solution will have to involve calling `allInfo()` on the base class, and then appending to the string that the base class implementation returns.

Since this is homework, I will refrain from implementing this for you!

Comment: Ah,alright. I can try that. I'm doing this as homework,and one of the requirements is to make the member variables and properties private. Should've probably mentioned that before posting.

Comment: You nailed it.Thanks a bunch. =)

Comment: Sounds like a good exercise with a very good lesson to be taught. Repetition is to be avoided because, amongst other reasons, it makes maintenance harder. If you have multiple identical distinct implementations of some code, then you have to find (the hard bit) and change (the easy bit) all of them when you want to make a modification.

Answer (score 2):

Make your members `protected` to access them via derived classes:

```
  protected:
            string title;
            string author;
```

Otherwise, they are invisible for derived classes.

[Private and Protected Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/):

> **Public** members of a class A are accessible for all and everyone.
>
> **Protected** members of a class A are not accessible outside of A's code,
>   but is accessible from the code of any class derived from A.
>
> **Private** members of a class A are not accessible outside of A's code,
>   or from the code of any class derived from A.

If you want leave them `private`, the other way is to create `protected` or `public` access methods for them.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the `private` members to:

```
protected:
    string title;
    string author;
```

This way the sub-classes can access them.