# What kind of data or function is better to be put in the protected area of C++ class?

Tags: c++, class

What kind of data or function is better to be put in the protected area of C++ class? And what's the benefit of doing it?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c).

Comment: This is one of the few areas covered in *any* C++ instructional material, no matter how well or poorly written.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the benefit part yes, but whether to put it or not ? Nay... most tutorials screw it up.

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of data or function is better to be put in the protected
> area of C++ class?

Items which you want to be accessible through inheritance.

> **And what's the benefit of doing it?**
>
> The protected keyword specifies that the public and protected members
> of the base class are protected members of its derived classes.
>
> Protected members are not as private as private members, which are
> accessible only to members of the class in which they are declared,
> but they are not as public as public members, which are accessible in
> any function. Protected members that are also declared as static are
> accessible to any friend or member function of a derived class.
>
> Protected members that are not declared as static are accessible to
> friends and member functions in a derived class only through a pointer
> to, reference to, or object of the derived class.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e761de5s.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The protected class members can be accessed by any classes derived from that class and friend classes.

Answer (score 0):

`protected` is nearly equivalent to `public`: any derived class might use, so the set of accessors is unbounded; a derived class might even make a `public` wrapper that directly call the base `protected` method if necessary.

As a result, my advice is simple:

- Data should be either `public` or `private`
- Methods should be either `public` or `private`, in general

The only exception for methods is that constructors, assignment operators and destructors can be made public to prevent the construction/copy/assignment/destruction of a base class without precluding its children to be constructed/copied/assigned to/destructed.

Comment: That is a bold statement. IMO `protected` is as close to `public` as `private`. Also why do you want to make a wrapper class, when you want to abuse system you can go `#define private public` or `-Dprivate=public -Dprotected=public -Dclass=struct`. There is much use to `protected` e.g. when designing interfaces you often write a public `virtual` caller, that in basic implementation "consists" of several `protected` stages. Then descendant classes are given much of freedom in their design, which is nice.

Comment: @luk32: it is bold, but it is necessary. Too many people fail to understand that you cannot rely on derived classes to maintain a class invariants; and `protected` is often used to open such a hole. I don't deny using `protected` cannot be convenient, I argue that using it however is bad design. Proper solutions might be slightly more complicated, though in practice it has never happened to me.