# Protected member is not accessible through a pointer or object

Tags: c++

Visual studio is telling me I can't access a member variable from and instance of a parent class. Something like this:

```
class Parent { 
protected: 
      int x;
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    void foo(Parent* p) {
        p->x;
    }
};
```

I'm new to c++, is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I’ve changed my mind: this isn’t a duplicate. True, the other question’s answers answer this question, but only incidentally. In addition, this question is much clearer and should be answered directly rather than be redirected.

Comment: That is wrong. If it's protected you cannot access the variable of `p`. But `Child` has a variable `x`, since it inherits it from `Parent`. Though it's impossible to access `p->x`. `p` has nothing to do with the `x` of `Child`. Was this helpful?

`protected` members of a class `Parent` are not accessible outside of Parent's code, but are accessible from the code of any class derived from `Parent', in this case `Child`.

Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c

Comment: You could declare <code>Child</code> as a friend of <code>Parent</code>. Just add <code>friend class Child;</code> to the definition of class <code>Parent</code>. This is okay if you are the maintainer of <code>Parent</code> and you know what all derived classes of <code>Parent</code> should really do with <code>x</code> (it is a design issue).