# How to treat inherited classes as a member object? c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Assume the following:

```
class A {
    public: 
        A();
    protected:
        int a;
};

class B : public A {
    public: 
        B();
};
```

My questions:

- Can I access (directly) the protected data members of A and maybe modify them without having to use public member functions?
- Can I treat A inside B as an "existing" object so that I can return A by reference and be able to modify its data member?

I am new to C++. I tried couple things to treat "A" as an object but I keep getting error messages. Here is one thing I have tried:

```
A & B::getA() {
    return A; //error: "A does not refer to a value"
}
```

Comment: Change `return A;` to `return *this;`

Comment: but how would I use `*this` to access the data member of that class? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Yes. Yes, except before A was constructed (in the initializer list of a `B()` constructor).

Comment: You don't need to use `this` to access data. Just type `a = ...` whatever.

Comment: @Olank1969 You can access it directly using `A::a`;

Comment: You should really pick a book, it will answer all your questions: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would you write it as an answer so I can mark it. Also, one last thing, if I passed an object of A by reference to a function inside B, can I still (directly) modify the data member of A that is inherited by B and assign it to the data member of the object being passed by reference? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a reference to your base class you can write

```
A & B::getA() {
    return *this;
}
```

to access `A`'s protected data member you can simply write

```
a = 5;
```

Comment: Would you please add an answer for this question too? If I passed an object of A by reference to a function inside B, can I still (directly) modify the data member of A that is inherited by B and assign it to the data member of the object being passed by reference? If yes, how?

Comment: For example, `void B::setA(const A & obj) { a = obj.a }`.

Comment: @Olank1969 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954049/how-to-treat-inherited-classes-as-a-member-object-c/36954405?noredirect=1#comment61465948_36954049

Comment: The link doesn't work! Please I really need your answer to understand this last question.

Comment: @Olank1969 The link works as intended. Why don't you simply try your code yourself?

Comment: I tried so much things, but nothing worked. Otherwise, I wont keep bothering you

Comment: @Olank1969 Well `void B::setA(const A & obj) { a = obj.a; }` should work. Did you simply forget the semicolon?

Comment: no I have the semicolon, but I get this error message "a is a protected member of A"

Comment: @Olank1969 Oh, yes. I always forget this, sorry. It's because `obj` is a different instance, and protected members cannot be accessed outside of the same instance.

Comment: @Olank1969 `void B::setA(const A & obj) { *this = obj; }` should work.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work also. it says "no viable overloaded ="

Comment: does this mean I have to overload the assignment operator ?

Comment: @Olank1969 There should be a auto generated assignment operator.. May be a problem with proper casting `void B::setA(const A & obj) { *static_cast<A*>(this) = obj; }`

Comment: It worked. Do you know what was the problem exactly so I can learn more about it?

Comment: @Olank1969 The problem was that you want to call `A:operator=(const A&)` but tried `B:operator=(const A&)` which isn't defined. Hence the cast to `A*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helps. Sorry for taking your time

Answer (score 1):

> Can I access (directly) the protected data members of A and maybe
>   modify them without having to use public member functions?

A protected member variable or function is very similar to a private member but it provided one additional benefit that they can be accessed in child classes which are called derived classes.

> Can I treat A inside B as an "existing" object so that I can return A
>   by reference and be able to modify its data member?

In B you can directly access to A (public and protected) method and attributes.

[Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c) here for more.