# How to access private variable from a parent class

Tags: c++

I have to do polymorphism for the *go() function* but i cant figure out how to access private variable *distance*. The complier keeps showing that 
‘int Transport::distance’ is private within this context
5 |      distance = 100;

Here is my code

**Transport.h**

```
#ifndef TRANSPORT_H
#define TRANSPORT_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Transport{
    private:
        int distance;
    public:
        int get_dist_travelled();
        virtual void go();

};

#endif
```

**Transport.cpp**

```
#include "Transport.h"

        int Transport::get_dist_travelled(){
            return distance;
        }
```

**Horse.h**

```
#ifndef HORSE_H
#define HORSE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Transport.h"
using namespace std;

class Horse:public Transport{
    public:
        void go();
};

#endif
```

**Horse.cpp**

```
#include "Horse.h"
#include "Transport.h"

void Horse::go() {
     distance = 100;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Transport.h"
#include  "Horse.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Horse kid;
    kid.go();
    cout<<kid.get_dist_travelled()<<endl;

}
```

Comment: You cannot. On the other hand, if it was `protected`...

Comment: That's what `private` does. It makes the variable inaccessible (even to derived classes). Maybe you want `protected`, instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/what-is-the-difference-between-private-and-protected-members-of-c-classes

Comment: In `Transport.h`, it has `#include <iostream>` but does not use it.  Include what you use.  Don't include what you don't use.  It also has `using namespace std;` which is Very Bad™, and even more so in a header file.

Comment: i changed it to protected

Comment: @Eljay thank you i m aware of this but i still dont know which one i need to put std:: in front of

Comment: You can't, at least not directly.   Two options are to (1) make the `distance` member `protected` or `public`  or (2)  call the inherited `get_dist_travelled()` - which is already `public` and directly accesses the `distance` member (since it is a member function of the base class).   I would prefer the latter - it achieves the required effect (obtaining (a copy of) the value of `distance` from the base class) and doesn't require changing the base class at all.   If you need to change the value of `distance`, add a `protected` or `public` member of the base class that can change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can on the one hand make the variable protected, or define the class as a friend class.