# protected members are not accessible in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, private-members

Why is that protected members in the base class where not accessible in the derived class?

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    int publicmemberA;

protected:
    int protectedmemberA;

private:
    int privatememberA;

    ClassA();
};

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
};

int main ()
{
    ClassB b;
    b.protectedmemberA; // this says it is not accesible, violation?
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access `protectedmemberA` **inside** `b`. You're attempting to access it from the outside. It has nothing to do with inheritance.

This happens for the same reason as the following:

```
class B
{
protected:
   int x;
};

//...

B b;
b.x = 0;  //also illegal
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the protected members are only visible *inside the scope* of class B. So you have access to it here for example:

```
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
    void foo() { std::cout << protectedMember;}
};
```

but an expression such as

```
someInstance.someMember;
```

requires `someMember` to be public.

Some related SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011/should-you-ever-use-protected-member-variables) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224966/private-and-protected-members-c).

Comment: tnx juan, any good situation on which a protected modifier is preferred? still cant gets its significance :(

Comment: I cannot think of a good reason to use a protected member variable. I have seen the use of protected functions when you want to allow derived classes to use some base class functionality, without making that functionality public. I would say, only use it if you really know what you are doing!

Answer (score 0):

You can only access `protectedmemberA` from within the scope of `B` (or `A`) - you're trying to access it from within `main()`